# How to send data from one user to other without storing data in database

Tags: php, xml, ajax

i got an assignment to make something similar to http://typewith.me .The problem i am facing is that i have to send xml through AJAX from one user to server(im using PHP) and the other user will receive it when he makes request through AJAX. But storing XML in database in the intermediate time will make it slow. So where else can i store the XML. Remember there can be multiple users and it all should be synchronized. Please Help.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have some specific reason to say "using a database is slow", or is that just an opinion you have? Databases can be plenty fast; it depends on how you work with them.

Comment: Have you looked at caching? Depending on your PHP build, it probably comes with APC.

Comment: I just came to know that we are restricted to use database or any method which saves a file on server e.g xml file. Is there any method to share data between all session considering the above restriction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can read from the Etherpad documentation, which is the engine used by typewith.me, it uses [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) as a database. In [this Etherpad fork](http://github.com/karteek/etherpad/blob/master/users-guide.md), the author suggests to use more powerful databases - such as MySQL - when the number of users exceeds 100.

To be honest, I would strongly suggest you to use a Database. You can still profile your web application, trying to identify and optimize your bottlenecks if the case.

Comment: Etherpad's [requirements](http://code.google.com/p/etherpad/wiki/Instructions) list MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

> But storing XML in database in the intermediate time will make it slow.

No, it won't. This is what databases are for - storing data for later retrieval.

TypeWith.me uses EtherPad, which uses the MySQL database as a backend.

Comment: Thanks alot. Ill then stick to MySQL and see how it performs.